# Segmentation fault - Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, segmentation-fault, ruby-1.8

I use the ruby 1.8.7 there are a good time, and I use this version of ruby with rails 3.0.x since of release of this version of rails. And I never got  a Segmentation fault error. But now, after start develop the ruby 1.8.7 with the rails 3.1.3, when I execute the webrick and I  surf  the application, I have the error below:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:380: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
```

The error is very inconstant , sometime happens with httputils of the webrick and sometimes with the  rack. 
Maybe the error have some relation with assets pipe line, because the errors happen before of some process like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/zh_cn.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 09:22:23 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/zh_cn.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/zh_cn.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/plugins/embed/jquery.wymeditor.embed.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 09:22:23 -0200 2011
```

Anybody can help me, about this issue. Since now I thanks for any help.

Thanks

Development log:

```
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/he.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/he.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/he.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/hr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/hr.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/hr.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/hu.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/hu.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/hu.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/it.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/it.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/it.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/nb.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/nb.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/nb.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/nl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/nl.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/nl.js - 304 Not Modified (4ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pl.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pl.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pt-br.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pt-br.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pt-br.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pt.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
cache: [GET /assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pt.js?body=1] stale, valid, store
Served asset /wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/pt.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
Started GET "/assets/wymeditor/wymeditor/lang/ru.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 28 11:57:36 -0200 2011
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb:232: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
Abortado
```

Abortado in English is Aborted

List of all my gems:

- actionmailer (3.1.3)

  - actionpack (3.1.3)
  - activemodel (3.1.3)
  - activerecord (3.1.3)
  - activeresource (3.1.3)
  - activesupport (3.1.3)
  - arel (2.2.1)
  - bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  - brI18n (3.0.4)
  - brazilian-rails (3.0.4)
  - brcep (3.0.4)
  - brcpfcnpj (3.0.4)
  - brdata (3.0.4)
  - brdinheiro (3.0.4)
  - brhelper (3.0.4)
  - brnumeros (3.0.4)
  - brstring (3.0.4)
  - builder (3.0.0)
  - bundler (1.0.15)
  - capybara (1.1.1)
  - childprocess (0.2.2)
  - coffee-rails (3.1.1)
  - coffee-script (2.2.0)
  - coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
  - columnize (0.3.4)
  - cucumber (1.1.0)
  - cucumber-rails (1.1.1)
  - database_cleaner (0.6.7)
  - devise (1.4.8)
  - diff-lcs (1.1.3)
  - dragonfly (0.9.8)
  - erubis (2.7.0)
  - execjs (1.2.12)
  - factory_girl (2.2.0)
  - factory_girl_rails (1.3.0)
  - ffi (1.0.9)
  - gherkin (2.5.1)
  - hike (1.2.1)
  - i18n (0.6.0)
  - jquery-rails (1.0.19)
  - json (1.6.3)
  - json_pure (1.6.1)
  - linecache (0.46)
  - mail (2.3.0)
  - mime-types (1.17.2)
  - multi_json (1.0.4)
  - mysql2 (0.3.11)
  - nokogiri (1.5.0)
  - orm_adapter (0.0.5)
  - polyglot (0.3.3)
  - rack (1.3.5)
  - rack-cache (1.1)
  - rack-mount (0.8.3)
  - rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  - rack-test (0.6.1)
  - rails (3.1.3)
  - railties (3.1.3)
  - rake (0.9.2.2)
  - rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
  - rdoc (3.11)
  - rspec (2.6.0)
  - rspec-core (2.6.4)
  - rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
  - rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
  - rspec-rails (2.6.1)
  - ruby-debug (0.10.4)
  - ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
  - rubyzip (0.9.4)
  - sass (3.1.11)
  - sass-rails (3.1.5)
  - selenium-client (1.2.18)
  - selenium-webdriver (2.8.0)
  - sprockets (2.0.3)
  - term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
  - thor (0.14.6)
  - tilt (1.3.3)
  - treetop (1.4.10)
  - tzinfo (0.3.31)
  - uglifier (1.1.0)
  - warden (1.0.6)
  - webrat (0.7.3)
  - wymeditor (0.5.0.rc2)
  - xpath (0.1.4)

Ruby version:
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299)
Arch:
[i686-linux]

The only stack trace that I get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:50
while timeout > 0
(rdb:2) n
[2011-12-28 16:22:52] ERROR #<Class:0xb6614868>: execution expired
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:in `timeout'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httprequest.rb:326:in `_read_data'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httprequest.rb:337:in `read_line'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httprequest.rb:240:in `read_header'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httprequest.rb:88:in `parse'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:54
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
   script/rails:6:in `require'
   script/rails:6
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:51
break if IO.select([sock], nil, nil, 0.5)
```

The error didn't happen with easily in debug mode, line by line. I did have just one stack trace, and I didn't get more than one time.

At this moment I disabled the asset pipeline, coffeescript and sass. And I didn't got more the error, but I don't have more these functions.

Comment: No stacktrace? Magic ball, come...

Comment: also need the version numbers of the gem files that have changed since the upgrade

Comment: Sorry, the final of post have all the gem of application

Comment: The log no have so much to say, the error happens suddenly, no explanation, and the webrick dies:

Comment: @user1018568: You should really run your application in gdb to get a stack trace of the crash (preferrably with debugging symbols), otherwise we can't help you much.

Comment: The error is very difficult to obtain a good stack trace. I did have debugged line by line of the webrick server and rack. I have a good  coverage of test in my application, and  the error didn't  threw at level of controller etc..I wasted more then 4 hours  trying get some good stack trace,because the error just appeared   in debug mode when i passed line by line with  'n'  command, when I press the 'c' the error happened in the same way when I surf in the application with browser , no stack trace.  Basically the error  threw when the rails server tried obtain  the assets, see the end of post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note from [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) says:

> Note that Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 have marshaling bugs that crash Rails 3.0. Ruby Enterprise Edition have these fixed since release 1.8.7-2010.02 though. On the 1.9 front, Ruby 1.9.1 is not usable because it outright segfaults on Rails 3.0, so if you want to use Rails 3 with 1.9.x jump on 1.9.2 for smooth sailing.

I've had very good luck with 1.9.2 and rvm makes it easy to switch between multiple versions of ruby. Would you be able to try this?

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much for your help. I and my company we agree that we will close the first release of this software with the assets pipe line turned off. When we finish this first release, we will do a lot of test, with different  version of ruby and until differents JavaScript preprocessor. Thanks for the tip about ruby 1.9.2. We will start the test with the ruby 1.9.2. When I to have some progress about it, I will post it.

Thanks